# Как вынуть элементы из списка после группировки itertools.groupby с сохранением структуры.Python

Tags: python, list

я только изучаю Python,постараюсь как можно подробнее описать суть проблемы.
Имеется два списка, которые нужно отсортировать и вывести отсортированные элементы в виде отельных списков.

```
elem1 = [21, 23, 67 , 85, 35]
elem2 = ["a", "a", "a" , "b", "b"]
```

Для группировки использовал itertools.groupby.
Вот весь код

```
from itertools import *


elem1 = [21, 23, 67 , 85, 35]
elem2 = ["a", "a", "a" , "b", "b"]

groups = []
keys = []

elements=zip(elem1, elem2)

for k, g in groupby(elements, key=lambda x: x[1]):
   groups.append(list(g))    
   keys.append(k)


OUT = groups, keys
```

Итогом является список ключей

```
[a, b]
```

и список с двумя вложениями

```
[((21,a),(23,a),(67,a)), ((85,b),(35,b))]
```

последний список нужно привести к виду:

```
[(21,23,67),(85,35)]
```

Перелопатил кучу информации, но никак не могу понять как это сделать.
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: А все промежуточные действия тоже для чего-то нужны, или это всё лишь способ получить `[(21,23,67),(85,35)]` ? Потому что последнее можно сделать сильно проще...

Comment: Да, нужен список ключей для дальнейшей работы.

Comment: Самое близкое, к чему я пришел это:
    for i in groups:
        for j in range(len(i)):
            sort.append(i[j][0])
тогда получаю список вида: (21,23,67,85,32)

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [((21,a),(23,a),(67,a)), ((85,b),(35,b))]
res = [[i[0] for i in el] for el in arr]
```

Comment: О, огромное спасибо, а где можно почитать про такую конструкцию?

Comment: @Ingkonstr [lists comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)

Comment: Премного благодарен!